# Qt 3D: Is Easing available for animation?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt3d

I am examining 3D capabilities of Qt 6.0.1 . I have copied a sample project, but it gives error that `"easing" does not have members` for line `easing.type :Easing.InQuad`:
Here is code:

```
            SequentialAnimation on y {
                loops: Animation.Infinite
                NumberAnimation {
                    duration: 3000
                    to: -150
                    from: 150
                    easing.type :Easing.InQuad
                }
                NumberAnimation {
                    duration: 3000
                    to: 150
                    from: -150
                    easing.type :Easing.OutQuad
                }
            }
```

[image: Easing does not have members - error in qml]

Why may this happen? Does it mean that suggested example is not working?

Comment: Have you run the code? It may be a false positive from the IDE

Answer (score 0):

I have used to trust IDE too much.

This is really a false positive from IDE. Code runs fine, animation seems correct.

This question may be closed.